# Android Kotlin Binding Custom Librarys to my code?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, binding

Hi i'm pretty new on kotlin and MVVM and would like to migrate on it with but i have some few problems on binding some librarys that i'm fond with when i was coding in MVP android-java so here.

I'm using this open source library for my pin https://github.com/poovamraj/PinEditTextField

How can i bind onTextCompleteListener to my xml?

```
  val linePinField = findViewById<LinePinField>(R.id.pf_input_passcode_lineField)
    linePinField.onTextCompleteListener = object : OnTextCompleteListener {
        override fun onTextComplete(@NotNull enteredText: String): Boolean {
          //  toast(enteredText)
            return true // Return true to keep the keyboard open else return false to close the keyboard
        }
    }
```

Here is my XML

```
  <com.poovam.pinedittextfield.LinePinField
        android:id="@+id/pf_input_passcode_lineField"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textSelectHandle="@drawable/text_handle"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:distanceInBetween="5sp"
        app:highlightColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:highlightEnabled="true"
        app:highlightType="currentField"
        app:isCursorEnabled="true"
        app:lineThickness="1sp"
        app:noOfFields="6" />
```

Please help/Guide me :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not know your library but i think i'll be works as normal EditText.

1. Create instance of `textLitner : OnTextCompleteListener` in you ViewModel
2. Create a `BindingAdapter` like this

   @BindingAdapter("addEditTextLstnr")
   fun bindEditText(editText: LinePinField, textListner: OnTextCompleteListener) {
     linePinField.onTextCompleteListener = textListner
   }
3. Then you can bind it in xml

   ```
   <LinePinField
       android:id="@+id/section_name"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       addEditTextLstnr="@{viewModel.textLitner}"
       />
   ```

   Try this approach